# Get a wrong timestamp, but its ASCII format is right

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got a timestamp and then I convert it into the ASCII format, however I found the timestamp is wrong by comparing with later timestamps. 
The ASCII format of the timestamp is right in the program, however the result doesn't match the result from python in the command line. There is a 8-second gap.

Is there any thing wrong?

Code

```
   def set_start_time(self, t):
        self.threadLock2.acquire()
        print(time.asctime( time.localtime(t)))
        self.start_time.value = t
        print("start_time=" +str(self.start_time) +"@"+str(hex(id(self.start_time))))
        self.threadLock2.release()
```

Output

```
set_start_time enter                                                                                                
Thu Oct 24 18:29:28 2019
start_time=c_float(1571941760.0)@0x7fb84aa6d710
```

Convert the timestamp in command line

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time
>>> time.asctime( time.localtime(1571941760.0))
'Thu Oct 24 18:29:20 2019'
```

Comment: You are losing precision by storing the time value in this `c_float` object (something from `ctypes`, I assume).  You need a `c_double` to match Python's normal `float` type.  You were lucky to get a value that's only 8 seconds off, the granularity of a 32-bit float of this magnitude is 128 I think.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks! You solve my problem!